# How can I cleanly achieve a consistent style for seaborn plots from different python files aimed at an academic paper?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am producing a lot of plots using python seaborn and would like to achieve something like a "house style".  Different python scripts are producing plots and I would like a consistent style across them, the ultimate destination being an academic paper or a thesis (LaTeX -> pdf).  For example, when submitting to a particular venue, the standard font might be sans-serif, so it would be good to switch that in one place for all the plots produced.

I know about `set_context()`, `set_style` and their standard options, but if I wanted more control, is it possible to centrally define the style and then use it in each script?  The docs suggest that something like this is possible: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html says that `style` is a "dictionary of parameters or the name of a preconfigured set" but it is light on details - where are these parameters?  Are they just straight matplotlib parameters?

I have seen https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html which sets out all the things you can tweak and save in a `matplotlibrc` file.  Is there a seaborn equivalent?

Comment: The matplotlib parameters that you link to are what seaborn is changing.

Comment: Thanks @mwaskom, I've just had a peek at the seaborn source - things make a bit more sense now.  Thank you for an awesome tool!

Comment: The docstrings for `set_context` and `set_style` are actually not very clear about this, although it is mentioned else where in the docs. If you could open an issue about that on the seaborn github, i think it could be improved.

Comment: FWIW i tend to solve this problem by doing something like [this](https://github.com/WagnerLabPapers/Waskom_PNAS_2017/blob/master/plotutils.py#L14).

Comment: Yes, that's really helpful, thank you, and I suppose all those rc's can be stored in an external config file easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the question here rather than in the comments, seaborn's theming system works entirely through the [matplotlib rcParams interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

All theme control in seaborn happens through code, but matplotlib also lets you define styles in a file that will either get picked up implicitly (if the file is named `matplotlibrc` and lives somewhere predictable) or explicitly (if you use the newer `plt.style.use` function and point it at a file with the `matplotlibrc` structure).

I'd prefer the more explicit approach (either using seaborn's `set_{theme,style,context,palette}` functions or matplotlib's `plt.style.use` function), for reproducibility reasons.

With the seaborn approach (explicitly enumerate the parameters in code) you don't have to worry about forgetting to include any additional files when you distribute the code. With the explicit `plt.style.use` command, you still need an external file, but it will be obvious what went wrong if it's missing. When you rely on the implicit `matplotlibrc` configuration, you can send someone your code, they won't get the same plots as you, and it won't be obvious why.